# gnuplot: Not enough columns for variable color

Tags: linux, runtime-error, gnuplot

I am executing the following gnuplot script:

```
set title "Efficiency scatter plot"
set xlabel "perf_1"
set ylabel "secondary report"
set log x
set log y
set xrange [0.1:40.0]
set yrange [0.1:40.0]
set terminal png medium
set output "./graph1.png"
set size square
set multiplot
set pointsize 0.3
set style line 6 pt 6
set datafile separator ","
set border 3
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
plot '/tmp/data.csv' using 3:1 with points pt 1 lt 3  lc var title     "perf_20140113131309", \
 '/tmp/data.csv' using 3:2 with points pt 1 lt 1  lc var title "perf_1"
plot x notitle
plot 2*x notitle
plot 0.5*x notitle
```

obtaining the following error message

```
 "script.gnuplot", line 20: Not enough columns for variable color
```

Could you please guide me in order to find what I am doing wrong.

By the way the gnuplot version is '4.6 patchlevel 3' the data.csv files used is

```
 0.1,0.1,40.0
 0.14,0.14,40.0
 0.32,0.32,40.0
 0.7,0.74,40.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `multiplot` mode like that. Why don't you just plot everything with a single `plot` command? `plot '/tmp/data.csv', x notitle, 2*x notitle, 0.5*x notitle`. And use `pngcairo` instead of `png` :)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but could you please point me (or send a link) the difference between png and pngcairo. Regarding the first point you are right, I do can do as you say, I am going to modify my script. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, the main advantages of the `pngcairo` terminal are the much higher quality of the line and font rendering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means, that you need to specify one more column in your `using` statement: The first one is the `x`-coordinate, the second one the `y`-coordinate. The one for the variable line color is missing.

Use e.g.

```
plot '/tmp/data.csv' using 3:1:0 with points pt 1 lt 3 lc var
```

to use the row number (zeroth column) as `linetype` index. You can also use e.g. `linecolor palette` so select the color from the currently defined color palette.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it worked perfect! Even thought it does not generate the graph I was expecting, it made the trick. Now the problem is related with the data. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of graph did you expect? The answer was only to show a working example. Do you need a specific color coding?

Comment: The point is that I am building a scatter graph with result from N files, from these N files I need to compare one against one in order to get the expected results according to the specification I received. But I was trying to do altogether.

Comment: Then you can try with iterations like `filelist = "file1 file2 file3"; plot for [i=1:words(filelist)] word(filelist, i) lt i` or similar.